# MySQl query Select all rows with same value in limit so that no value is left outside the limit defined

Tags: mysql

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ MSG_ID ║ RANDOM_ID ║  MSG  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║        22 ║ apple ║
║      2 ║        22 ║ bag   ║
║      3 ║         0 ║ cat   ║
║      4 ║         0 ║ dog   ║
║      5 ║         0 ║ egg   ║
║      6 ║        21 ║ fish  ║
║      7 ║        21 ║ hen   ║
║      8 ║        20 ║ glass ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

Want to fetch 3 records in a lot   such a  way that all the data of a particular random_id is picked up .

**Result Required:**

```
║ MSG_ID ║ RANDOM_ID ║  MSG  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║        22 ║ apple ║
║      2 ║        22 ║ bag   ║
║      3 ║         0 ║ cat   ║
```

**Current Result:**

```
║ MSG_ID ║ RANDOM_ID ║  MSG  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║        22 ║ apple ║
║      3 ║         0 ║ cat   ║
║      4 ║         0 ║ dog   ║
______________________________
```

**Query Used:**

```
SELECT  ID,Random_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(message SEPARATOR ' ' ),FLAG,mobile,sender_number,SMStype  
FROM    messagemaster
WHERE   Random_ID > 0
GROUP   BY Random_ID
UNION
SELECT  ID,Random_ID, message,FLAG,mobile,sender_number,SMStype
FROM    messagemaster
WHERE   Random_ID = 0
order by random_id LIMIT 100;
```

I don't want to pick up records  using  group by.I want to fetch all the records w rt random_ids .Like , if there is a random_id for which there are 3 records and if the query has limit =3 , then i want all the data w r t those random_id to be picked up.
The situation is if I fetch rows with limit 100 , i dont want that some of the data with the random id  present in the result set is not picked. 
For example if i am picking records limit by 3 then for `random id=22` , all records with `random id =22` should be picked .

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
 SELECT b.*
   FROM
      ( SELECT x.*, SUM(y.cnt)
          FROM 
             ( SELECT random_id,COUNT(*) cnt FROM messagemaster GROUP BY random_id) x
          JOIN
             ( SELECT random_id,COUNT(*) cnt FROM messagemaster GROUP BY random_id) y
            ON y.random_id >= x.random_id
         GROUP 
            BY x.random_id
        HAVING SUM(y.cnt) < 4
      ) a
   JOIN messagemaster b
     ON b.random_id = a.random_id;
```

Comment: I have provided more explanation .Please check.. Thanks

Comment: actually I am  calling this query  in loop  .Once the 100 rows are executed  next 100 rows is fetched .So, once the first lot is  fetched in my result set, I dont want that there is any row left in DB with the random _id   already fetched in the first lot.

Comment: For Instance :SELECT * 
  FROM messagemaster 
 
 ORDER 
    BY random_id DESC
     , msg_id LIMIT 5; would leave two rows of which there would be one row with random_id =21 ..My requirement is either all the row with random_id =21 is picked up  or leave all the data with that random_id